# How do I mock or stub an AJAX call that gets executed on load?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have an angular app the calls 2 services before bootstrapping, and I'd like to mock or stub those calls. Otherwise, karma tries to perform those calls and it keep showing errors in the console.

How would I do that?

See the `getConfig()` and `getUser()` functions bellow:

**JavaScript:**

```
import appConstant from './app-gouvernementales.constant.js';
import appConfig from './app-gouvernementales.config.js';
import appRun from './app-gouvernementales.run.js';
import AppComponent from './app-gouvernementales.component.js';

const requires = [
  'ngMessages',
  'ngRoute',
  'ngSanitize',
  'permission',
  'permission.ng',
  'ngMockE2E',
];

const app = angular
  .module('app-gouvernementales', requires)
  .config(appConfig)
  .run(appRun)
  .component('appGouvernementales', AppComponent)
  .name;

// create and bootstrap application
getConfig()
  .then((config) => {
    angular.module('app-gouvernementales')
      .constant('APP_SETTINGS', appConstant(config));

    return { url: `${config.protocol}://${config.host}`, uid: config.shibbolethUid };
  })
  .then(data => getUser(data.url, data.uid))
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
    document.location.href = '/erreur/role';
  })
  .then((_user_) => {
    const user = _user_.data;

    angular.module('app-gouvernementales')
      .constant('USER', user);
  })
  .then(() => {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['app-gouvernementales']);
  });

function getConfig() {
  const initInjector = angular.injector(['ng']);
  const $http = initInjector.get('$http');

  return $http.get('/gouvernementales/app-gouvernementales.config.json')
    .then(response => response.data);
}

function getUser(url, uid) {
  const initInjector = angular.injector(['ng']);
  const $http = initInjector.get('$http');

  return $http.get(`${url}/roles`, { withCredentials: true, headers: { 'X-uid': uid } });
}

export default app;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do it with `$httpBackend`.

```
var $httpBackend;
var yourMockedObject = {};

beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function (_$httpBackend_) {
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_
    $httpBackend.expect('GET', 'the/url').respond(yourMockedObject);
}));

afterEach(function () {
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
});
```

But ideally you dont want to bootstrap the whole app when unit testing, but rather just the specific module you want to test. In that case you could mock the data passed to that module.

Comment: Does this mean that when I choose which file karma should load, it should not be the "entry point file" that imports everything?

Comment: Ok, so I've separated the root app module creation from the bootstrap file, and configured Karma to only load the app module file and all specs. Most of my tests work, but for some reason, some random component or service just wont load... and I just can't figure out why...

Comment: It almost seams like a previous test is influencing the next ones

Comment: You should load all files in your karma conf. But in your tests only instantiate the relevant module `angular.mock.module('somePartOfTheAppModule');`

Comment: So after lots of testing, some modules will load, some wont, some components or services will load, others wont... After checking with 3 developers, this just is getting stranger and stranger, and there doesn't seam to be a solution. I can't believe tests are so difficult to setup in 2016.